# Redirect include to index page

Tags: php, include

I have include "content.php" that loads in "index.php". How do I redirect the include to load into "index.php" when user requests direct URL access to "content.php"?

Comment: Some pseudocode illustrating your question, please.

Comment: You should accept an answer when you are satisfied ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can set a constant in your `index.php` before your `include content.php;` then in `content.php` check if it's defined. If not redirect to `index.php`. Example:

```
<?php // index.php

define('IN_APP', true);

include 'content.php';

?>

<?php // content.php

if(!defined('IN_APP')){ 
    header('Location: index.php') 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your content.php:

```
if( strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php') != 0 ) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])` to find the name of the script currently being executed.

It will return the file name even if it is the index file and called with a url like this `path/`.
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would return only `/`.